# Can I filter query results in DynamoDB with ComparisonOperator.IN on the sort key of my local secondary index?

Tags: java, java-8, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to do a query filter with ComparisonOperator IN on the sort key but I am getting this error.

> QueryFilter can only contain non-primary key attributes

I understand that the ComparisonOperator IN is not indexable, and thats why I am not setting it as a RangeKeyCondition. However, I want to just perform a scan filtering the query results.

Here is my code:

```
Tax hashKeyValue = new Tax();
hashKeyValue.setUserId(userId);
Condition scanFilterCondition = new Condition()
.withComparisonOperator(ComparisonOperator.IN)
.withAttributeValueList(taxIds.stream()
                        .map(t -> new AttributeValue().withS(t))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList())
                       );
Map<String, Condition> conditions = new HashMap<>();
conditions.put("id", scanFilterCondition);
DynamoDBQueryExpression<Transaction> dynamoDBQueryExpression = new DynamoDBQueryExpression<Transaction>()
                .withIndexName(null)
                .withConsistentRead(false)
                .withHashKeyValues(hashKeyValue)
                .withQueryFilter(conditions);
return getMapper().query(Transaction.class, dynamoDBQueryExpression);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround but works fine for me.

I used another GSI to query the table, such that the sort key I am filtering for is not a primary key anymore.

I am open for other solutions or comments :)